# How to declare one of a class properties to be compulsory if the other is entered in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In the following example, I want the user of the class to be able to use it without having to enter a message unless visible is set to true.

```
type ClassProps = {
  visible: boolean;
  message: string;   // message should be compulsory if visible
}
```

Comment: You can use a [sum type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) for that purpose. Let me know, if you need more help.

Comment: @ford04 I don't really see how this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to build this up as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of two object types: one where `visible` is `false` and `message` is optional, and the other where `visible` is `true` and `message` is required:

```
type ClassProps = { visible: false; message?: string; } | { visible: true; message: string }
```

This, I think, behaves as you desire:

```
const ok1: ClassProps = { visible: false }; // okay
const ok2: ClassProps = { visible: false, message: "invisible" }; // okay
const ok3: ClassProps = { visible: true, message: "visible" }; // okay
const bad: ClassProps = { visible: true }; // error!
//    ~~~ <---
// Property 'message' is missing in type '{ visible: true; }'
// but required in type '{ visible: true; message: string; }'
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IAoCcD2YlQLxQDeUAbgJZJkBGcEAXFAGYJxIQDcUAthCggOYQA-AyTB0ZAHb9OAXygAfIqQrVaDcQFcO3XkgH0oYidKiyAUOYDGmSWKiYA1gEYG8ZGiw58y8pRqGzKzQspwA9GEOjggg1rb2TgBMbogoGNi4BMR+aoEsbAA0unyCDABEUjkBZWbhkU4xcXbAUQDMKR7p3lkq-upQWhBFPCWGZVW0NaFQEVGNNs1QVAgAJh1pXpm+qgEa6Nq1M5EQ6FjoAITms1A3AH73UAA8ALSvV5FdJ6BQAOQj+oIflAKNwKJRTFIBuBoD9sjt+oM5D93ktNC10BAAI6aMgYlbAyRQyC-OF9QyI4oAwzGKQyMw-IA)